# Launching debugger in windows service

Tags: c#, debugging, service, visual-studio-2013

I'm having problems with the `Debugger.Launch()` function. In my windows service I'm trying to debug a job that it has to do but for some reason the JIT function opens a new instance of VS (which is ok) but for some reason it's not hitting the `Debugger.Launch()` line but does execute the next line.

```
    public override void DoJob()
    {
        Debugger.Launch(); //---> doenst stop here
        Debug.WriteLine("Job started"); //-----> but writes this
    }
```

I've tried numerous thing as in resetting VS completely , import settings from a VS where it works , rebooting , restarting VS, clean and rebuild (i think 6000 times about now), deleting all bin folder and obj folders, etc.

Anyone has a clue why I can't debug but my `Debug.WriteLine` works ?

Comment: Where did you set the breakpoint?

Comment: Like EVERYWHERE. Breakpoints on almost EVERY line. This stressing me out

Comment: And it breaks nowhere? Did you do a release or a debug build? Are the pdb's in the output folder?

Comment: Yeah it's solved now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
Debugger.Launch();
Debugger.Break();
```

that should do it